# How to add/insert common header to several word files?

Tags: ms-word, header, header-files, word-2007

I have several word files for different topic in my office folder. I want to insert a common header/footer to all the word files. Moreover when I change the header/footer at one place, I want the same placed in all word files also be changed. Please help. It is easy in HTML (like header file) but I want in MS-Word.

Comment: Please take a moment to read about asking questions on StackOverflow in the [help]. This site is for programming questions, not for end-user topics. Please ask non-programming questions on SuperUser or another site that targets the end-user, such as Microsoft Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a header.docx file to store the required header text and insert that file content as a linked field in other documents as mentioned below:

1. Open the Insert > Field Dialog
   [image: Insert Field Dialog]
2. Select IncludeText under Field names
3. Enter the file name of the header file (if you are storing the file on same folder) or the complete path of the file.
4. make sure Preserve formatting option is checked if required
5. Click OK

[image: Insert Field Dialog]

This will help you to have a common header for all your files. However, it won't update automatically when you update the header.docx file. Once you update the header.docx, you can right click the inserted field text in other documents and click "update field". Alternatively you can write a macro to update fields in your document.

Comment: You should point people with off-topic questions to the correct place to ask such questions. This question is not about programming, it's an end-user question and thus belongs on SuperUser or a similar site.